# Map function to an element in tuple

Tags: python, haskell, generator

I have in mind something that I would do in Haskell like this:

```
f :: Int -> (Int, Int)
-- for example:
f = `divMod` 12
foo :: [Int] -> (Int, Int)
foo = map (fmap (+1) . f)
-- foo [10, 11, 12, 13] = [(0,11),(0,12),(1,1),(1,2)]
```

Is it possible to do such mapping to tuple in Python elegantly (without looking inside `f`?) The best I could come with was:

```
def foo(lst):
  for x in lst:
    a, b = f(x)
    yield a, b + 1
```

another possibility is

```
def foo(lst):
  return map(lambda x: (f(x)[0], f(x)[1]+1), lst)
```

But I like neither solution. I do not like the first one, because it's not a single expression and could not be so easily inlined. The other solution has this property, however it's ugly because it unnecessarily calls `f()` twice in each iteration. Is it possible to somehow unpack the result inside the iteration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just map `lst` to `f` first:

```
try:
    # Python 2, forward compatible version of map
    from future_builtins import map
except ImportError:
    # Python 3, map is already an iterator
    pass

def foo(lst):
    return [(fxa, fxb + 1) for fxa, fxb in map(f, lst)]
    # or a generator expression for lazy evaluation
    # return ((fxa, fxb + 1) for fxa, fxb in map(f, lst))
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I found one solution that has the two desired properties, but it's not very readable:

```
def foo(lst):
  return map(lambda a, b: (a, b+1), *zip(*map(f, lst)))
```

Comment: make it list iteration`[(a, b+1) for a,b in *zip(*map(f, lst))]`

Comment: Why the need to use `map()`? Why not just use a generator expression instead?

Comment: @ling7334: at that point the `*zip(*map(..))` is even more of a waste of cycles.